# AngularJs ui-view not getting data from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

[image]My AngularJs ui view don't receive any data from it's controller. Here's the code

```
                .state('website-pages.home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    templateUrl: 'website/home.html',
                    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
                        $scope.data="temp data"
                    }]
                })
```

And the website/home.html is

```
  <h3>{{data}}</h3>
```

But don't show the value inside data.

Comment: are you sure the state is getting loaded? any errors on console?

Comment: @gaurav5430 no error even in console the data shows.

Comment: can you add a fiddle or plunkr ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 It's a angularJS template. normally my view get data from it's controller but in this template not receiving.I am attaching more code.

Comment: M.Doye yes the semicolon is a mistake but not the problem for sending data to view.

Comment: Put alert in controller. And see in console. Controller is in invoking or not

Comment: @Himesh Suthar Yes controller is invoking and console shows tha data value.

Comment: how would the console be showing data with the code you posted here? are you *sure* you don't have a duplicated route? one that has a `console.log` statement in the controller code?  The only other reason that this code might produce no output is if there is some CSS hiding the content area.

Comment: I have tried console.log earlier but didn't post that code . And CSS not effecting the value let me post the output.

Comment: Is htmlClass a service? Where is the controller referencing htmlClass from? Try commenting out the two assignments before your data assignment in your controller...

Answer (score 1):

Your code wrong in format of controller parameter. I don't see array is accepted type of controller parameter [in here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateproviderstatestatename-stateconfig). It just should be a function or string name.

This code should work:

```
.state('website-pages.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'website/home.html',
    controller: function($scope){
        $scope.data="temp data"
    }
})
```

Comment: How do you config 'website-pages' state? Upload your code to see

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax of defining a controller:

[ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers)

```
.state('state2.list', {
    url: "/list",
    templateUrl: "partials/state2.list.html",
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
    }
});
```